# Top part of checkbox do not work after resizing it and resetting materialize

Tags: css, checkbox, materialize

The top part of my checkbox do not word anymore after resizing it and resetting materialize.

Here is sample code:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <style>
    [type="checkbox"].reset-checkbox,
    [type="checkbox"].reset-checkbox:checked,
    [type="checkbox"].reset-checkbox:not(checked) {
      opacity: 1;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    [type="checkbox"].reset-checkbox+span::before,
    [type="checkbox"].reset-checkbox+span::after,
    [type="checkbox"].reset-checkbox:checked+span::before,
    [type="checkbox"].reset-checkbox:checked+span::after {
      display: none;
    }
    
    [type="checkbox"].reset-checkbox+span:not(.lever) {
        padding-left: 0px;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="">
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="reset-checkbox" style="width:20px;height:20px;" checked="checked" name="firstCheck"/></label>
    </form>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Here is the jsfiddle for you to try to click the top part of the checkbox if you want:
https://jsfiddle.net/j4oxgmtc/

Any idea or solution?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andreas responded to that question in a comment: [Exclude materialize css for some specific checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51614859/exclude-materialize-css-for-some-specific-checkbox/51615520?noredirect=1#comment111212195_51615520)

''This happens, because  is an inline element. You can set display: inline-block for it to fix it.''

Here is the modified working code: https://jsfiddle.net/vL3fsqjb/2/

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<style>
[type="checkbox"].reset-checkbox,
[type="checkbox"].reset-checkbox:checked,
[type="checkbox"].reset-checkbox:not(checked) {
  opacity: 1;
  position: relative;
}

[type="checkbox"].reset-checkbox+span::before,
[type="checkbox"].reset-checkbox+span::after,
[type="checkbox"].reset-checkbox:checked+span::before,
[type="checkbox"].reset-checkbox:checked+span::after {
  display: none;
}

[type="checkbox"].reset-checkbox+span:not(.lever) {
    padding-left: 0px;
}
</style>
```