# How to skip materialize css file getting applied to ag-grid components

Tags: javascript, html, css, materialize, ag-grid

I have a `.cshtml` file which contains *search/upload/download/save* buttons that uses `materialize.min.css` for styling of these buttons and a `ag-grid` in the same page to show the uploaded file data in the grid.
So the page is referred to both `materialize.min.css` and ag-grids **javascript** community edition file i.e. `ag-grid-community.min.js`.

I wanted to select each rows of ag-grid and then send it to backend for processing. So i have enabled ag-grids column property `checkboxselection`. But unfortunately the `checkbox` in ag-grid is not working (i.e. not able to check the checkbox) since `CSS` of `materialize.min.css` are getting applied to `checkbox` element instead of ag-grids checkbox `CSS`.

I have tried below ways to sort this out but none helped,

1. Changed the order of CSS files in my page.
2. Wrote a separate CSS file and copied ag-grids checkbox related CSS and added `!important` tag to each of its properties.
3. Tried using ag-grids `cellclass` property.

As per my project structure, I can't have separate `CSS` file for *search/upload/download/save* buttons because its written as a separate framework.

Is there any way to bypass `materialize.min.css` file getting applied to `ag-grid`?

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same issue recently and the following worked for me, inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51615520).

Add the following CSS to undo the Materialize formatting as per the link above:

```
[type="checkbox"].reset-checkbox,
[type="checkbox"].reset-checkbox:checked,
[type="checkbox"].reset-checkbox:not(checked) {
  opacity: 1 !important;
  position: relative !important;
  pointer-events: inherit !important;
}

[type="checkbox"].reset-checkbox+span::before,
[type="checkbox"].reset-checkbox+span::after,
[type="checkbox"].reset-checkbox:checked+span::before,
[type="checkbox"].reset-checkbox:checked+span::after {
  display: none !important;
}

[type="checkbox"].reset-checkbox+span:not(.lever) {
  padding-left: 10px !important;
}
```

Add the following to your ag-grid. This will add the class to all the checkboxes. It needs to called dynamically on the scroll event because ag-grid use DOM Virtualisation.

```
gridOptions.onBodyScroll = function(){
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".ag-checkbox-input");
  for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].classList.add('reset-checkbox');   
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After many trial and error method, having the below `css` code in new `css` file and then refereeing it in working page worked for me.

```
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked), [type="checkbox"]:checked {
position: initial;
left: initial;
opacity: initial;
background-color: initial !important;
cursor: default !important;
appearance: checkbox !important;
box-sizing: border-box !important;
margin: 3px 3px 3px 4px !important;
padding: initial !important;
border: initial !important;
left: 0px !important;
}

input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"] {
box-sizing: initial;
padding: initial;
background-color: initial !important;
cursor: default !important;
appearance: checkbox !important;
box-sizing: border-box !important;
margin: 3px 3px 3px 4px !important;
padding: initial !important;
border: initial !important;
}
```